# Detect circular dependency before insert

Tags: mysql

I'm having 2 MySQL tables

```
Person Table
============
Name
----
person1
person2
person3

Person Dependencies
===================
person   dependency_person
--------------------------
person1  person2
person2  person3
person3  person1
```

in the `Person Dependencies` table, is it possible to check for a circular dependency before inserting a row like in the third row(person3 person1)

Comment: you need [recursive queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with  `LEAD` window function to make the number of relation rows then do self-join

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) rn
  FROM Person
)
SELECT c1.Name,c2.Name 
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Name,rn,LEAD(rn,1,1) OVER(ORDER BY Name) n_rn
  FROM CTE
) c2
ON c1.rn = c2.n_rn
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=170ae0569922ec97b9fff64edacbe644)